# Android kernel compiling error

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, android

When compiling the kernel, if I choose Ethernet Gadget (with CDC Ethernet support) or Network Control Model (NCM) instead of the Android composite device, I get an error:

```
drivers/built-in.o:coresight-tmc.c:function tmc_etr_store_out_mode: error: undefined reference to 'usb_qdss_close'
drivers/built-in.o:coresight-tmc.c:function tmc_etr_store_out_mode: error: undefined reference to 'usb_qdss_open'
drivers/built-in.o:coresight-tmc.c:function tmc_disable: error: undefined reference to 'usb_qdss_close'
drivers/built-in.o:coresight-tmc.c:function tmc_enable: error: undefined reference to 'usb_qdss_open'
drivers/built-in.o:coresight-tmc.c:function tmc_enable: error: undefined reference to 'usb_qdss_close'
Makefile:878: recipe for target '.tmp_vmlinux1' failed
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
```

Kernel version: 3.4.0

Toolchain: google arm-linux-androideabi-4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coresight-tmc.c` seems to refer to Coresight Trace Memory Controller, which seems to be a kernel/hardware debugging tool on ARM architecture.

You may have found an undeclared dependency in the kernel configuration: the Trace Memory Controller seems to depend on the Android composite device, but the kernel configurator is not aware of this fact and so allows you to choose a configuration that includes the Trace Memory Controller driver but not the Android composite device.

Your options with the kernel version you're using are:

- keep the Android composite device in your kernel configuration to satisfy Coresight's dependency, or
- disable the `CORESIGHT_*` configuration items in your kernel configuration, and so give up Coresight support.

Since the kernel version 3.4.0 is no longer in active development, there's probably no point in reporting the bug unless you can reproduce it with a newer kernel version: the oldest kernel version with active long-term upstream support is 3.16.60 at this time.